# Seperating by new line in an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Hey guys I'm new to coding. So I'm trying to return every other line of a text document. The text document is written like:

00:54

on that but anyways let's just go ahead

00:56

and jump straight into this the first

00:57

expense that people think they're gonna

00:59

I've found a way to do this using the following code:

```
 ArrayList<String> arrL = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    
        for(String word : "this exact strategy with even a similar10:55pfroduct here but that's gonna wrap up".split("/n")) {
    arrL.add(word);
}
   for (String a : arrL) 
            System.out.println(a);
```

The problem I face is that when I copy/paste from my text document, which is 19 pages long, i get the unclosed string literal error. I understand why I get this error ,but what would be a way to fix this?

Comment: 1. new-line literal is `"\n"` (using backslash), 2. you may get that error because the text you're pasting may contain `"` character(s) which needs to be escaped within Java string too  `"\"field\":123"`

Comment: Most IDE's (i.e Eclipse, Intellij), will autoescape special characters and insert necessary newlines into strings if you copy and paste into a set of double quotes (`""`). This is probably your best bet if this is a one time thing, otherwise, look into just reading directly from the file: https://www.java67.com/2012/11/how-to-read-file-in-java-using-scanner-example.html

Comment: What is stopping you from reading data directly from the file? I would suggest not to copy the file contents in your claas file

Answer (score 0):

Since your file is huge, recommended way would be reading data directly from the file.

If you are running Java 8+ and

If you want to simply read and collect each line of your file into an `ArrayList` then:

```
List<String> collect = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(yourFilePath));
```

If you want to skip blank lines and then collect the remaining data:

```
List<String> collect = Files.lines(Paths.get(yourFilePath))
            .filter(line -> line.length() > 0)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Taking a step forward, if you want to skip all the `hh:mm` strings from your file and collect the remaining data:

```
List<String> collect = Files.lines(Paths.get(yourFilePath))
            .filter(line ->  !line.matches("^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$")) // regex to match HH:mm format
            .filter(line -> line.length() > 0)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: No specific reason. Thanks for suggesting. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

You should read directly from the file and store it in a variable instead of using it as a constant literal.

```
String fileName = ""; // Complete file path    
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)));
```

You can use content variable instead of constant string literal